# How should I configure two subnets to see each other?

Tags: networking, router

I'm very much a newbie when it comes to networking so apologies if there's something obvious that I should know. It's a bit hard to put the whole situation on the question but what's currently happening is:

- I have two ISPs. One has an ONU configured as a bridge and connected to the router I use.
- We'll call this ISP1 which is not behind CGNAT. I can't configure the ONU but the router is completely mine.
- The other ISP, ISP2 is behind CGNAT. So their ONU is currently configured as a router, which configuration is limited since it's locked by the provider.
- ISP1 has 192.168.1.0/24 and ISP2 has 10.0.0.0/24.
  Since ISP1 is not behind CGNAT, my server is connected to it. My server is running unRAID hosting my NAS, web server, Plex, game servers, and pihole.

So what I would like to do is have devices under ISP2 network to be able to see the server on ISP1 network to use the NAS and if possible use pihole as well. What is the network topology for this configuration if possible? I have one unmanaged switch if that helps. I don't mind if I should change the IP range on any of the routers.

Comment: What kind/model of routers? Do they have a "static routes" configuration? Does at least one of them have anything like VLANs or multiple LANs (e.g. selecting which LAN ports are in which 'group' or 'vlan')? While this would _technically_ be a simple topology that falls under "literally the basic job of a router", many home wifi routers are not flexible at all, and it might turn out that it's easier to turn one of the Linux servers into a router instead (having two Ethernet ports would help).

Comment: Only one of the routers has configuration for static routing (ASUS TUF-AX5400). Non allows for VLANs though so that is a problem. I'll look into this, and thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Routing on just one of them _might_ be enough, and the routes can even be defined directly on PCs that are accessing the other network; but a direct connection probably isn't going to work out if neither of the routers can handle a 3rd network. (An unmanaged switch will not help.) Does any of your servers have at least two Ethernet interfaces (or a spare PCIe slot for installing a second Ethernet port)?

Comment: Also – what does "using Pihole" entail, exactly? Does a Pihole system act as an IP gateway, or is it just a DNS server? (DNS servers can be in distant subnets, but gateways cannot; a gateway must be local.)

Comment: I use pihole to act as a DNS server that filters out specific domains in a blacklist (ads, analytics, etc.). I guess this issue will be solved along with the routing issue. My server can have a 2nd network card installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two options:

##### Merging the subnets into one

It would be possible to configure the ASUS router as a second gateway in ISP2's subnet. The ISP1 subnet would then disappear and all hosts would be in the same 10.0.0.0/24 subnet, all of them using ISP2's gateway *except* those which are manually configured to use the ASUS router as gateway. As local subnet communications do not involve a gateway at all, the hosts could freely talk directly to each other despite being told to use different gateways.

(Multiple gateways do not conflict – multiple *DHCP servers* do.)

To do this:

1. Disable "DHCP server" on the ASUS router. If it does UPnP, make sure to disable that as well.
2. Configure the ASUS router's LAN interface to have an address from the ISP2 router's range.
3. Connect both routers' LANs directly (through a switch also counts as "direct").
4. Manually set IP addresses on the servers that need to use ISP1.

   If they're told to use the ASUS router as "default gateway", then they'll use ISP1; if they get addresses/gateways via DHCP, then they'll use ISP2.
5. Don't forget to adjust "port forwarding" rules on the ASUS router accordingly.

##### Keeping two separate subnets

With two routers, this would be easier if *one* of them supported multiple networks (e.g. being able to dedicate one of the ports to a second LAN). The hardware of the TUF-AX5400 would certainly be capable of it, so it's unfortunate that the firmware doesn't expose such capabilities.

So you'll need a third router, one which *can* be connected to multiple networks. One of your servers would work, if it has at least two Ethernet ports (or a free PCI Express slot for a new NIC).

The inability to configure static routes on one of the ISP routers is also unfortunate, especially when it's on the "client" side that needs to initiate the connections (it would be slightly less of a problem if it were on the side that's being accessed). If you can't configure the correct route on ISP2's router, you'll have to do it on each computer individually.

To do this:

1. Connect the server to both networks using its *separate* Ethernet ports.

   (The unmanaged switch is only useful if one of the existing routers has no free ports, but it will *not* help if the new server-to-become-router only has one Ethernet port – you'd need a managed switch with VLAN support in that situation.)
2. Configure both interfaces with appropriate IP addresses. (It needs a *stable* address for each interface – DHCP is okay if the ISP routers properly remember what lease to issue across reboots, a manual IP address would be preferred otherwise.)
3. Enable "IP forwarding" in the server's OS, if not already enabled. For Linux it can be done through sysctl:

   ```
   net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
   net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding = 1
   net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
   net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding = 1
   ```
4. Configure routes on each side, for the opposite network, via the server as the "gateway". For example, computers on the ISP2 side would need a route for 192.168.1.0/24 via 10.0.0.x (whichever address the server has on the ISP2 facing NIC).